# Prediction using lm on a data frame input - model is not finding input variables

Tags: r, input, prediction, lm

This is a very basic question (I am a novice...). I am trying to test out a simple predict using a linear model but I don't seem to be correctly specifying the dataframe of inputs.

In the call to predict, I keep getting a message that newdata has 12 rows but the variables have 21 rows - I think that is because the inputs variables are not being found. I saw a solution posted earlier for a single input (that suggested to use a vector instead of a data frame) but that does not seem to fix my issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
################Code is below ######################

# Reading in a csv Text File. Has Headers Quantity, Income, Price and 21 rows of values
CSVData <- read.table("C:/Users/.../CSVInput.txt",header=T,sep=",")

Model=lm(CSVData$Quantity~CSVData$Income+CSVData$Price)

###Creating a new test data set for prediction##################
BindCols1=seq(5,16,by=1)
BindCols2=seq(20,75,by=5)
PredFrame=data.frame(cbind(BindCols1,BindCols2))
colnames(PredFrame) <- c('Income','Price')
colnames(PredFrame)

coef(Model)
pc=predict(Model,PredFrame)
```

When I run the code, I get a

> "Warning message: 'newdata' had 12 rows but variables found have 21
>   rows"

. Also, it does not use the new inputs (from PredFrame) for the prediction but instead uses the data that was used to fit the model.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!!!

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
Model <- lm(Quantity ~ Income + Price,data=CSVData)
```

The `formula=...` argument to `lm(...)` references column names in the data frame specified in the `data=...` argument. Once you've done the fit, that information is stored, so you can use `predict(Model,newdata=...)` and as long as `newdata` has the same columns as those on the RHS of `formula`, it will work.